# How to instruct Ajax Minifier to remove console.log from javascript

Tags: minify, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I have lines in my js files like this

```
console.log('FunctionName()');
```

The default Ajax Minifier settings do not remove these lines from the .min.js output.

I noticed in this discussion a [conversation about Kill switches](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/discussions/260685).

Looking at the Kill Switch [page here](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=JavaScript%20Kill%20Switches). I noticed there is this switch:

```
/// <summary>
/// remove "debug" statements
/// </summary>
StripDebugStatements = 0x0000000000800000,
```

I am not using the command line, I am referencing the DLL. This is how I have implemented it.

```
CodeSettings jsSettings = new CodeSettings()
            {
                KillSwitch = 800000,
            };
```

and then later the actual minifier method.

```
string fileMinified = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(fileSource, jsSettings);
```

How can i remove console.log()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make you calls to console.Log from methods in "Debug" namespace ( http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Preprocessor )

Sample:

```
var Debug = {};
Debug.myTrace = function(message){
 console.log(message);
};

///#DEBUG 
someDebugOnlyCode();
///#ENDDEBUG
```

All calls to Debug.myTrace will be removed during minification ("debug" namespace), as well as call to someDebugOnlyCode (inside DEBUG/ENDDEBUG comments).

Comment: Is this still the case? The provided link no longer exists, and my logs are still being shown, following this approach.