# How to remove JS logging calls in our prod build of our mvc3 web app?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, bundling-and-minification

We've got a lot of calls to our logging methods (that just wrap console.log) all throughout our JS in our MVC3 web app and I'd like to remove them from the JavaScript when we build our test and production builds.

Currently we're using the [bundling and minification nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Optimization/0.1) to bundle and minify our JS into one big minified file but I'd like to have it rip out the calls to the logging methods as well.

We do have a mechanism in place that replaces the logging methods with empty functions so they won't do any work in production, but they are still called and various arguments are passed in.  On top of this, there are "large" strings that are passed and those could be removed, reducing filesize.

The ideal solution in my mind would be to somehow parse the JavaScript and detect / remove the calls to those methods.  Preferably in some sort of JavaScript engine and not just a regular expression.

Either way, I just want my calls to my logging methods removed in the final JavaScript that is served up in production.  Does anyone know how I'd accomplish this additional minification?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816845/how-to-instruct-ajax-minifier-to-remove-console-log-from-javascript

Comment: very nice, that looks really promising. I'll have to thoroughly investigate that

Comment: Valamas hey that "preprocessor" stuff works great, can you post that as an answer and i'll accept it?

Comment: thanks, but you should delete this question. It is not my answer to give. have a good one.

Comment: Well one thing that is interesting that I've discovered is that this prepropcessor type stuff was added to the microsoft ajax minifier.  I was not aware that they re-used the same minifier for the `IBundleTransform` work that they did for MVC4.  Technically this question is somewhat different because I'm specifically interested in the new bundling and minification  stuff, not the ajax minifier.  Since the new stuff is likely to be more popular and come up in searches more, I'll go ahead and leave this question.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, the `IBundleTransform` interface was designed for this scenario.  In RC bits here's what we envisioned:

```
new Bundle("~/bundles/js", new LogRemoverTransform(), new JsMinify());
```

Basically, you construct a bundle and chain two transforms, first stripping your log methods, and then running through normal minification.  Prior to RC, you would have to do the composition inside of your `IBundleTransform`.

Comment: Whoa cool! Did you work on the bundling? If so, thanks and great work!

Comment: Great job, I love how we can just pull in transforms as nuget packages now

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own implementation of [IBundleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.ibundletransform_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that first removes calls to your logging methods via a regular expression and then calls the default bundling and minification functionality.  As long as your calls are fairly simple, it shouldn't be hard to come up with.  It *might* get tricky though, depending on how you call your logging code.

For example, it'd be fairly hard (for me) to build a regex that would catch the entirety of a logging call like this:

`NS.log(function () { return "this is going to be hard to parse"; }());`

But, as long as you don't log like that, it shouldn't be a difficult regex to write.